# hackerrank - min max sum test case fail

Tags: javascript

The problem I am doing is on hackerrank, and I don't understand what I'm missing here feels like this should be working.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem?isFullScreen=true

> Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

Test Case 0:
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

Test Case 1:
arr = [7, 69, 2, 221, 8974];

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    var temp = 0;
    var mini = 0;
    var max = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        temp += arr[i];
        if (i == arr.length - 2) {
            mini = temp;
        }
    }
    max = temp - arr[0];
    console.log(mini + ' ' + max);
}
```

Test case 1 fails
My output: 299 9266

Expected output: 299 9271

Comment: Why do you feel like it should be working? Your code appears to assume sorted input.

Answer (score 0):

In question and in test cases it does not say sorted array. You should sort it before putting in for. Add this before your loop `arr = arr.sort((a,b) =>  a - b)`

```
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    var temp = 0;
    var mini = 0;
    var max = 0;
    arr = arr.sort((a,b) =>  a - b)
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        temp += arr[i];
        if (i == arr.length - 2) {
            mini = temp;
        }
    }
    max = temp - arr[0];
    console.log(mini, max)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're assuming that the input array is *always* sorted which is *not* true.

You can find out the maximum number and minimum number and then subtract them from the total sum.

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
  let 
    maxNum = arr[0],
    minNum = arr[0];
  arr.forEach((a) => {
    if (a > maxNum) {
      maxNum = a;
    }
    if (a < minNum) {
      minNum = a;
    }
  });
  const totalSum = arr.reduce((s, a) => s + a, 0);
  console.log(totalSum - maxNum, totalSum - minNum);
}

miniMaxSum([4, 1, 3, 2, 5]);
```

You can also sort the array and then calculate the sum of the smallest `n-1` values and the largest `n-1` values, where `n` is the length of the original array.

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const minSum = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1).reduce((s, n) => s + n, 0);
  const maxSum = arr.slice(1).reduce((s, n) => s + n, 0);
  console.log(minSum, maxSum);
}

miniMaxSum([4, 1, 3, 2, 5]);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution which is passed all the tests.
I hope it helps.

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
    const total = arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b , 0)
   const sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => a -b)
   const min = arr[0]
   const max = arr.reverse()[0]
   console.log(total-max, total-min)
}

let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
let arr2 = [-2,56,874,255,32,478965]

console.log(miniMaxSum(arr1))
console.log(miniMaxSum(arr2))
```